# How tall is Taniquetil?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Taniquetil is the dwelling place of the Valar and the highest point on all Arda and tallest mountain on Middle-Earth. Is there any insight on what the height of Taniquetil is?

Comment: Higher than Thangorodrim, Hyarmentir, Kalorme and peaks of Orocarni. Lower then the Lamps and Walls of Night.

Comment: Um, Taniquetil has never, _ever_ been on Middle-Earth. Do you have a reference for it being the highest mountain in _Arda_? Remember that at various times the Valar drew the Pelori (presumably including Taniquetil) higher up.

Answer (score 3):

The precise height is never revealed; we just know that it's the tallest...anything in all of creation.

In *Atlas of Middle-earth*, Karen Wynn Fontsad speculates that Thangorodrim, serious runner-up for title of "highest mountain in Arda", was 35,000 feet high:

> Prior to *The History* [*of Middle-earth*] the only references [to Thangorodrim] were the text and a drawing<sup>1</sup> by Tolkien that showed the central peak in the distance. The text stated that these were the "mightiest towers of Middle-earth." *[...]* In the drawing, the central tower, as seen from the Pass of Sirion, appeared immense - far higher than the Ered Engrin. It would have to have been some five miles in diameter at the base and some 35,000 feet high!
>
> <sup>*The Atlas of Middle-earth* Part 1: "The First Age" "Thangorodrim and Angband"</sup>

Assuming she's correct about this<sup>2</sup>, Taniquetil must be higher than 35,000 feet. But that's about the best we can do.

---

<sup>1</sup> This drawing is a 1928 pencil sketch titled "Tol Sirion". A coloured version (not coloured by Tolkien), included below, was printed in *The Silmarillion Calendar 1978*

[image]

<sup>2</sup> And bear in mind that this is Fonstad's intuition, based on her expertise as a cartographer and interpretation of a (very old) pencil drawing. It may or may not be anything close to correct

Comment: For comparison, Mount Everest is about 29,000 feet high, and jets flying long distances typically have cruising altitudes around 35,000 feet. There is not enough oxygen in Earth's atmosphere at those altitudes to sustain life, so oxygen must be supplied to humans at those altitudes. So it's pretty darn high.