# Which mountain is higher, Caradhras or the Halifirien?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

I wonder which mountain's peak likely has the higher elevation above sea level, the Caradhras (highest mountain of the Misty Mountains, located above Khazad-Dûm) or the Eilenaer/Halifirien (at the border between Rohan and Gondor, highest of the seven beacon mountains, probably highest mountain of Rohan and among the highest peaks in Gondor and the Ered Nimrais).

Both mountains are covered in snow so that both peaks must be higher than 8,000 ft (snow line at midlatitudes) while on Eilenaer there's the beacon patrol so its peak must be low enough that hypoxia is no issue (reportedly 75% of climbers experience altitude sickness above 10,000 ft, and I guess the patrol exchanges once in a while). Therefore I'd rather go with Caradhras, and the Caradhras actually looks higher to me seen from Eregion than the Halifirien seen from Edoras though we don't know how high the plains of Rohan are above sea level.

Comment: Don't you know, Numenoreans would have to be among the 25% who could take it.

Comment: We generally don't know enough about heights of mountains in Middle-Earth to be likely to answer such questions, unless something new was revealed in Nature of Middle-Earth. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235197/whats-the-tallest-mountain-in-middle-earth

Comment: @suchiuomizu In the link the Halifirien isn't considered among them, while Caradhras is. Obviously the Caradhras.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron I guess the beacons that are on peaks bordering Rohan might be patrolled by Rohirrim as well.

Comment: @Aragorn Elessar  There is no reason to believe that the Halfirien beacon was on the highest peak of the Halfirien Mountain.  It had to be in a position with clear lines of sight to the surrounding beacons, and so high enough to be seen over the curature of the Earth.  If the beasons were tens of miles apart, they would probably have to be only a thousand or two feet above the plain at their feet.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205915/height-of-mountain-ranges-in-middle-earth

Comment: @Mithoron Thank you. The answer there implies the Halifirien may be higher than Caradhras (more than 12,000 ft in elevation).

Comment: @M.A.Golding When the beacons were lighted the beacon of Halifirien when seen from Edoras seemed on or close to the peak.

Comment: @M.A.Golding --- The Halifirien beacon was at the summit. See parts (iii) and (iv) of Cirion and Eorl in the Unfinished Tales. The Beacon was reached by an ancient stone stairway. Isildur had his men build this stairway when Elendil's tomb was placed on Halifirien; it leads to the summit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caradhras is higher. It is a mountain (in the common sense of the word),
whereas Halifirien is a hill (again in the common sense).

When the Company is in the foothills of the Misty Mountains (The Ring
Goes South, in The Fellowship of the Ring).  Gandalf says it will take
two marches to reach the top of the Redhorn Gate pass which is far
lower than the summit of Caradhras (otherwise it wouldn't be a pass).
In contrast, Cirion and Eorl walk up Halifirien, hold a ceremony at
the summit and walk back down in a single day (part (iii) of Cirion
and Eorl in the Unfinished Tales). Notably, they start their descent
as the evening is setting in, reaching their camp at the foot of the
hill in time for supper. Starting a descent from a mountain in the
evening would be utter madness; had the descent been long they would
simply have camped at the top.

It's also worth pointing out that the Lord of the Rings explicitly
states that the Beacons were in the foothills of the White Mountains,
not on the tops of the mountains themselves (Minas Tirith, in the Return
of the King). There is an extensive discussion of this here:

[Do the beacon lighters really live on top of the mountains?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/96054/4935)

An important conclusion there is that beacons on top of very high mountains would be almost impossible for a pre-technological state to maintain.

Comment: I know the other name and it's wrong because it implies it is a hill (Amon) while in fact it's a mountain (Orod). Should I ever become King of Gondor I will rename the mountain back to Eilenaer.

Comment: @AragornElessar --- Call it what you like, but Cirion and Eorl describes two ocassions on which men climbed to the summit, and refers to Amon Anwar as a hill throughout.

Comment: "Hill" is also arbitrary, but you usually don't refer to permanently-snow-covered mountains as hills. Mt Sunday on which Edoras is built is a hill. Amon Sûl the weathertop is a hill. Amon Dîn is on the verge between a hill and a mountain, it is snow-covered in spring.

Comment: @AragornElessar --- I've added more detail.

Comment: Thank you. Wad Cheber in your link goes into detail why I call the Halifirien a 'mountain', not a hill. However I don't understand why you think beacons on very high summits would be silly. The higher they are the farther are they visible. Can you elaborate on that? Either that or remove that last sentence from your answer, please.

Comment: Beacons on mountains would pose two problems. Firstly if they are above the clouds, they will be invisible on cloudy days, secondly if hey are on snow covered mountains, they will also be less visible during the day, due to a lack of contrast, as the white mountain top is very bright on its own.

Comment: @trikPu Thank you. Though I think the "low" cloud layer is rather an effect of Middle-earth's curvature than the peak actually being above cumulus clouds. Clouds can be as low as sea level which is called fog. If beacons are on hills it would imply a not-so-far distance between Edoras and Minas Tirith, the Middle-earth continent would be rather tiny. And in winter you have snow anyway, and if you lit them at night there'd be contrast.

Comment: @AragornElessar --- Apologies for the long delay. I've been rather busy and have had next to no time for Stack Exchanging. I have made the edit.